# Oracle text index (Context) keep growing

Tags: oracle, text, oracle-text

In my application I needed to search through many varchar columns from differents tables.

So I created a materialized view in which I concatenate those columns, since they exceed the 4000 characters I merged them concatenating the columns with the TO_CLOBS(column1) || TO_CLOB(column)... || TO_CLOB(columnN).

The query is complex, so the refresh is complete on demand for the view. We refresh it every 2 minutes.

The CONTEXT index is created with the sync on commit parameter.

The index then is synchronized every two minutes.

But when we run the optimize index it does not defrag the index. So it keeps growing.

In ctx_user_indexes I see how optimize drops the docid count but tokens doesnt shrinks. But when I   use  the  REBUILD parameter in the index  optimization it works correctly (drops down number of rows in DR$TEXT_INDEX_IDX$I).

Any idea ?

Thanks, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a job to decrease the number of rows works.